# how can i remove punctuation except ! and ? in sentiment analysis in text mining using python

Tags: python, regex, punctuation

I am working on a text mining project in sentiment analysis. some sentence makes better sense when they have ! and ?. I am using a regular expression technique

```py
text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]".format(a), ' ', text)
```

where `text` is a list of strings.

with this, all punctuations are removed, but I would like to keep ! and ? and remove the rest.

Comment: `[^A-Za-z!?]`? You already have a character class to exclude. Just add them to that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the `?` and `!` characters in your regular expression:

```
text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z!?]".format(a), ' ', text)
```

Comment: i don't want to remove ! and ?, all other punctuation except those two

Comment: Precisely, that regular expression will select all characters that *aren't* in the a-z and A-Z range, plus ! and ?. So `re.sub` will remove all punctuation except ! and ?. :P